# How many ways are there to permute the elements of the set [7] so that an even number is in the first position?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As the title asks, how many ways are there to permute the elements of the set $[7]$ so that an even number is in the first position?

This is a question from "A Walk Through Combinatorics" by Bona.

Update: I think I may have figured it out, but there are no answers to this in the book, so some verification would be great. I know the total number of possible permutations of $[7]$ is $7!$. And it seems to me that the chances of an even number being in the first position would be $\frac{3}{7}$, so the total number of permutations with an even number in the first position would be $\frac{3}{7}(7!) = 2160$. Is this correct? If so, it was much simpler than I thought.

Comment: You can put even numbers in $4$ ways at the first place. And then permute the other six positions. So, $4×6!$ ways.

Comment: @AlapanDas There's three evens in [7] - 2, 4, 6. So it'd be $3 \times 6!$, right? That seems to be the same final answer I got in my edit above, but in a different way. This is probably a better way of looking at it. Thank you!

Comment: Oh. Sorry, then it will be $3×6!$. You are welcome.

Comment: In my opinion, your original solution is the best way of looking at it. However, if there are two different ways at looking at something, looking at it *both ways* is better than either one of them. Particularly in combinatorics.

Comment: If you are sure that the number of combinations starting with any chosen number is the same, your approach is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be 3(6!). Because there are only 3 ways to chose the first number then the second is 6 then 5 and so on.